# Add env var to commit message

Tags: git, bash, commit

How do I have to add an environment variable to my commit message in Linux?

```
VERSION="1.0.0"

git commit -m "we add version " + $VERSION + " and that's it"
```

But that seems not to work. Anyone who can help me with it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
VERSION="1.0.0"
git commit -m "we add version $VERSION and that's it"
```

No need to concatenate the strings using `+` , inside double quotes spaces are preserved.

Answer (score 9):

A mistake I've made, is to the surround the `-m` message with `''`. This will cause the message to just be "`$YOUR_VAR`" and not the content. Instead, use `""`

ex:

```
  git commit -m '$YOUR_VAR' # INCORRECT
  git commit -m "$YOUR_VAR" # CORRECT
```